# Retrieve Value from SqlDataReader and Pass to switch or if statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, switch-statement, sqldatareader

I'm having an issue passing a value from a `SqlDataReader` object to a `switch` statement - or anything for that matter. Short of it is that I'm reading the column from an employee table that shows their role. In order for the proper tools to be presented to them, I need to know what their role is. By the time I hit the switch, rec is empty.

```
using (SqlCommand readEmployeeRecords = con.CreateCommand()) {
    readEmployeeRecords.CommandText = "select * from dbo.Employee where employeeID = @employeeID and password = @password;";
    var empID = new SqlParameter("employeeID", employeeID);
    var pass = new SqlParameter("password", password);
    readEmployeeRecords.Parameters.Add(empID);
    readEmployeeRecords.Parameters.Add(pass);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = readEmployeeRecords.ExecuteReader()) {
        string rec = "";

        while (reader.Read()) {
            rec = reader.GetString(5);
        }

        switch (rec) {
           case "Busboy":
               BusboyForm bus = new BusboyForm();
               bus.Show();
               break;

           case "Waiter":
               WaiterForm wait = new WaiterForm();
               wait.Show();
               break;
       }
}
```

Comment: What was the query that you executed? is that query fetched any records?

Comment: Is `rec` contains `DBNull` or just empty string after assigned with `GetString`? Are you sure that 5th (or 6th if zero-indexed) column contained proper string you want to fetch in?

Comment: Your `rec` will return the last value in datareader. It is the value that you want, right?

Comment: Preceding code is below, having trouble formatting... 


using (SqlCommand readEmployeeRecords = con.CreateCommand())
                {

                    readEmployeeRecords.CommandText = "select * from dbo.Employee where employeeID = @employeeID and password = @password;";
                    var empID = new SqlParameter("employeeID", employeeID);
                    var pass = new SqlParameter("password", password);
                    readEmployeeRecords.Parameters.Add(empID);
                    readEmployeeRecords.Parameters.Add(pass);

Comment: Query returns records... if i check the value prior to the switch, I receive the data I want.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Post has been edited and code from comments added

Comment: You do realize only 1 value of `rec` will enter the switch. You should also have a default case in there which could probably help in this case with identifying what the value being passed in is

Comment: thanks all. yes, there should only be one value of the rec coming into the swtich. there is no default case because the whole thing is in a try/catch block.

Comment: Are you only working with that one value from the recordset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to post a comment, so an answer will have to suffice.

Based on the code you provided, `rec` would still contain the value when it gets to your switch statement.

Cases are case-sensitive, are you sure that the `'Busboy'` is in the table and not `'BusBoy'`? Also, does your table return additional whitespace in the string, i.e. `'BusBoy  '`?

It sounds like you are hitting the `default` case of your switch statement and hence not getting the behavior expected.

Comment: Agreed. So you think he should add `Trim()` and `ToLower()` when he is populating **rec** and then his `case` statements should be adjusted .

Comment: Thanks, Phil. It was hitting the default case, it wasn't actually empty.